# Go to parent directory inline

Tags: bash, shell, fish

I was wondering if it’s possible to go to parent directory of a file inline. I know I could type `cd ..` and it would. However, what if I wanted do something like `echo $(find . -name “xyz.png”)..`and it would  return the parent directory of the file instead of the path to file. Or instead of a file I search for a folder, and want to return path to the parent directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `dirname` to strip off the last part of a path.  Combined with `find` in your examples it would give you just the parent directory of whatever was found.  You could use that in cd as in `cd $(find -name "xyz.png" | xargs dirname)` if that's the sort of thing you're trying to do.

You can also use the `-type d` option to find to have it only find directories if you want to match directory names instead of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

```
  function dirs_ofFile
  {
      find -name "$1" | xargs dirname 
  }
```

then

```
$ cd $(dirs_ofFile xyz.png | sed 1q)   # in case there is more than one.
```